# Class "PHPUnit_Framework_Assert" not found

Tags: php, phpunit

I am getting the following error on Windows:

`Fatal error: *Uncaught Error: Class "PHPUnit_Framework_Assert" not found in C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase.php:98 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Calculator.php(4): require() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase.php on line 98*. Using php 8.1.1`

Other PHP applications are working well but I am new to Php Unit. The class `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase` does exist in TestCase.php but I don't see its parent (`PHPUnit_Framework_Assert`) anywhere. This is my code:

```php
<?php
//http://localhost/calculator.php
require dirname(dirname(__FILE__)).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '.\php\pear\PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase.php';
use PHPUnit\Framework\Assert; 
class Calculator
{
 
    public function add($a, $b)
    {
        return $a + $b;
    }
 
}
class CalculatorTests extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    private $calculator;
 
    protected function setUp()
    {
        $this->calculator = new Calculator();
    }
 
    protected function tearDown()
    {
        $this->calculator = NULL;
    }
 
    public function testAdd()
    {
        $result = $this->calculator->add(1, 2);
        $this->assertEquals(3, $result);
    }
 
}
?>
```

Comment: A class with that name has not existed for years. I suggest you read up-to-date documentation such as the official [Getting Started with PHPUnit](https://phpunit.de/getting-started/phpunit-9.html).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. That is the link that I used. I did the install (composer approach), played around for a few hours and couldn't figure it out. Next I uninstalled, reinstalled with phar and played around. I am getting the above error. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. I wonder if the issue is that I am using windows and trying to find ways to modify the steps for windows. Is there documentation for windows install or is it something else? Thanks.